# Is there a smart data reading function in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I usually use `pandas.read_csv` to get data from a file. When I use this function I need to set a separator and to specify if there is a header in the file.

Is there a way to pass this tasks to the program? Can't program find out itself  if there is header and what separator is used?

If it is possible, i would like to go further. Can't the function figure out in itself in what format dates are stored and then get all the dates as date objects?

It would be ideal if user can call `read_data` function with a file-name as the only argument and get the data. The function should automatically use the appropriate lower level reading and parsing functions for the type of data being read. It should work for data in a CSV file or in an Excel file.

Is there something in this direction?

Comment: The datetime formatting can be scanned by pandas, see:   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#inferring-datetime-format  --- but much of the rest of this is overly hopeful.